# Product photo gallery on product page

Tags: product, product-images

On the productpage we want to display a URL below the product images, that navigates to a new page with only the gallery of the product images of the specific product.

Especially for mobile users, so that they can view the productimages better and full width on their mobile device.

What is the best/easiest way to do this?

And also if possible we want to create the URL like this: http://www.domain.com/producturl/gallery

Thanks!

Comment: yes.it possible.. but product url append marked it critical

Comment: @AmitBera Thanks! How is it possible without the URL request?

Comment: yes. are want to do this on page?

Comment: @AmitBera I want to create a seperate page, with only the media gallery of that product.